# Updating data in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, phpmyadmin

I have a database and a datagridview. I want to update existing that is in phpMyAdmin. Here's my code:

```vb
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=server;password=server;database=heavisa_database"
    Dim rabit As MySqlDataReader

    MysqlConn.Open()

    Dim pin As String
    pin = "UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee SET (Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid.Text & "', Nat_ID = '" & txtnatid.Text & "', First_Name = '" & txtfirstname.Text & "', Middle_Name = '" & txtmiddlename.Text & "', Surname = '" & txtsurname.Text & "', NSSF_No = '" & txtnssfno.Text & "', KRA_Pin = '" & txtkrapin.Text & "', NHIF_No = '" & txtnhifno.Text & "', Residence = '" & txtresidence.Text & "', Mobile_No = '" & txtmobileno.Text & "', Email = '" & txtemail.Text & "', Job_Group = '" & cbojobgroup.Text & "', Employment_Date = '" & dtpemploymentdate.Text & "') WHERE Employee_ID like '%{0}%'"

    Try
        con = New MySqlCommand(pin, MysqlConn)
        rabit = con.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Update Successful.")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Here's the problem, when I run the program I get the sql syntax error at line 1.

I've tried seeing whether I placed an extra single quote and double quotes but everything seems fine. what could I have done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your SQL query

```
UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee 
SET (Employee_ID = ..., Nat_ID = ..., First_Name = ...,
     Middle_Name = ..., Surname = ..., NSSF_No = ...,
     ....
     ....
     .... )
WHERE Employee_ID like '%{0}%'
```

You need to remove the parenthesis between `SET` and `WHERE` as below

```
UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee 
SET Employee_ID = ..., Nat_ID = ..., First_Name = ...,
     Middle_Name = ..., Surname = ..., NSSF_No = ...,
     ....
     ....
     .... 
WHERE Employee_ID like '%{0}%'
```

You also need to use parameterized query to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and use [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to make sure the `SQLConnection` is closed and disposed after the query is executed. Since your query is an update query, you don't need `SqlDataReader` and you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader`

```vb
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click

    Dim pin As String
    pin = "UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee SET Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, Nat_ID = @Nat_ID, First_Name = @First_Name, Middle_Name = @Middle_Name, Surname = @Surname, NSSF_No = @NSSF_No, KRA_Pin = @KRA_Pin, NHIF_No = @NHIF_No, Residence = @Residence, Mobile_No = @Mobile_No, Email = @Email, Job_Group = @Job_Group, Employment_Date = @Employment_Date WHERE Employee_ID like '%{0}%'"

    Try
        Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection
            MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=server;password=server;database=heavisa_database"

            Using con As New MySqlCommand(pin, MysqlConn)

                With con
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtemployeeid.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nat_ID", txtnatid.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", txtfirstname.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middle_Name", txtmiddlename.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtsurname.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NSSF_No", txtnssfno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KRA_Pin", txtkrapin.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NHIF_No", txtnhifno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Residence", txtresidence.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_No", txtmobileno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Group", cbojobgroup.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employment_Date", dtpemploymentdate.Text)
                End With

                MysqlConn.Open()
                con.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("Update Successful.")

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code has helped but now there's another problem. When I open localhost to check if it has done the update I see the entire fields (for one record) deleted. Wish I could attached a screenshot here but unfortunately I can't because I don't have enough reputations to do so (according to the site)

Comment: Are you saying that the entire fields became empty string? If so, try to check if the values of `txtemployeeid.Text`, `txtnatid.Text` etc are empty. You can do so by putting a break point in `btnupdate_Click` and debugging.

Comment: Yes the fields are empty. I am updating existing records. I am updating from a DataGridView.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `txtemployeeid.Text`, `txtnatid.Text` etc when updating? Also, is this winforms or web app?

Comment: It is winforms. I've counter checked. The fields are empty.

Comment: How does the form look like? If `txtemployeeid`, `txtnatid` etc are *outside* the datagridview, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: They are inside the datagridview. Perhaps I should take a screenshot. Is it possible if I send it via email

Comment: The problem with empty fields is way out of context of this question. You need to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you can't add an image, then upload the image somewhere else i.e http://imgbox.com/ and provide the link in the new question.

Comment: screenshot is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023305/updating-data-in-phpmyadmin-part-2