# Update query makes the fields empty in the database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, phpmyadmin

I asked a question previously concerning updating data in a datagridview with phpMyAdmin. You can refer to it by following link -->[Updating data in phpmyadmin part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31019856/1905949)

The code works quite OK, but now the problem is that when I check for the updated data in localhost all I see are empty fields. Below is the screenshot of my vb in design. I have labelled the textboxes as per my database. The textboxes in the screenshot are set to be invisible on running my winform. [image: Screenshot of vb design]

What exactly could be the problem?

---

@Kakarot 
Here is what I initially had

MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=server;password=server;database=heavisa_database"
        Dim rabit As MySqlDataReader

```
    MysqlConn.Open()

    Dim pin As String
    pin = "UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee SET (Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid.Text & "', Nat_ID = '" & txtnatid.Text & "', First_Name = '" & txtfirstname.Text & "', Middle_Name = '" & txtmiddlename.Text & "', Surname = '" & txtsurname.Text & "', NSSF_No = '" & txtnssfno.Text & "', KRA_Pin = '" & txtkrapin.Text & "', NHIF_No = '" & txtnhifno.Text & "', Residence = '" & txtresidence.Text & "', Mobile_No = '" & txtmobileno.Text & "', Email = '" & txtemail.Text & "', Job_Group = '" & cbojobgroup.Text & "', Employment_Date = '" & dtpemploymentdate.Text & "') WHERE Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid1.Text & "'"

    Try
        con = New MySqlCommand(pin, MysqlConn)
        rabit = con.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Update Successful.")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

And here is what I currently have (credit goes to one Mr. ekad for it)

Dim pin As String
        pin = "UPDATE heavisa_database.new_employee SET Employee_ID = @Employee_ID, Nat_ID = @Nat_ID, First_Name = @First_Name, Middle_Name = @Middle_Name, Surname = @Surname, NSSF_No = @NSSF_No, KRA_Pin = @KRA_Pin, NHIF_No = @NHIF_No, Residence = @Residence, Mobile_No = @Mobile_No, Email = @Email, Job_Group = @Job_Group, Employment_Date = @Employment_Date WHERE Employee_ID like '%{0}%'"

```
    Try
        Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection
            MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=server;password=server;database=heavisa_database"

            MysqlConn.Open()

            Using con As New MySqlCommand(pin, MysqlConn)

                With con
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtemployeeid.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nat_ID", txtnatid.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", txtfirstname.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middle_Name", txtmiddlename.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtsurname.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NSSF_No", txtnssfno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KRA_Pin", txtkrapin.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NHIF_No", txtnhifno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Residence", txtresidence.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_No", txtmobileno.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Group", cbojobgroup.Text)
                    con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employment_Date", dtpemploymentdate.Text)
                End With

                con.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("Update Successful.")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The first code gave me an error (refer to the link above). The second code works but it's emptying my fields instead of updating.

Comment: How do you bind the data to the datagridview exactly?

Comment: bind to the database in mysqladmin? is that what you mean? If so then I don't think I have done that, neither do I know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you need a datagridview here? If you just want to enter those textboxes and update the record with the entered Employee ID, I don't think you need a datagridview. You can put those textboxes outside of the datagridview and remove the datagridview.

Comment: The idea was to display all names of employees in that datagridview. That's why I went for it.

Comment: And once I do that then I can do changes to a record and update it to my database

Comment: Can you please tell us what you enter in each textbox *before* you click the update button? Please reply by saying something like: I entered "abc" to `txtemployeeid`, "123" to `txtnatid`, "martin" to `txtfirstname`, and so on. It's important to know what you enter in each textbox so we can check whether the query is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

How did you updated your tables in your database? It should be like:
(Im gonna take my code for an old project that I did)

```
Private Sub disconnect()
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub connect()
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString
    conn.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveEdit.Click

connect()
Dim query as string
Dim command As New MySqlCommand

query = "Update `tblcandidates` set firstname = '" & txtEditFname.Text & "', lastname = '" & txtEditLName.Text & "', position='" & cboEditPosition.Text & "', fullname = '" & fullname & "' where recNum = '" & txtRec.Text & "'"



command.Connection = conn
command.CommandText = query

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

disconnect()
End Sub
```

Comment: If this code is the inspiration of [your new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31045369/1905949), then this answer doesn't solve the problem at all. MartinBaraza said in the question comment: **The idea was to display all names of employees in that datagridview.**, so if you really want to answer this question, then try to help @MartinBaraza understand how to bind data to datagridview first.

Comment: @ekad , dude, what hes asking in this post is ***why is his datas not showing in the database***. Not on the ***datagrid*** view thing. Thats in his other post, not here.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, just a simple question, is `heavisa_database.new_employee` a table? It's really wise to properly name them, you can put `tbl` before your desired name if its a table, and `db` before the name if its a database. Just to prevents confusions. And I think you dont need a `reader` when updating records in your table, correct me if I'm wrong :p

Okay, to be honest, I don't really understand much the code that Mr. ekad provided. Here's a code you can try. And oh, you don't really need the bracket after the `SET`.

```
//Global Vars
Dim connectionString As String = "server=localhost;userid=server;password=server;database=heavisa_database"
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
```

First, let's make some functions for ease (you can put this anywhere in your code):

```
//remember that conn is our MySqlConnection
Private Sub connect()
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString
    conn.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub disconnect()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

So, event for your update button:

```
connect()

Dim pin As String
pin = "UPDATE new_employee SET Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid.Text & "', Nat_ID = '" & txtnatid.Text & "', First_Name = '" & txtfirstname.Text & "', Middle_Name = '" & txtmiddlename.Text & "', Surname = '" & txtsurname.Text & "', NSSF_No = '" & txtnssfno.Text & "', KRA_Pin = '" & txtkrapin.Text & "', NHIF_No = '" & txtnhifno.Text & "', Residence = '" & txtresidence.Text & "', Mobile_No = '" & txtmobileno.Text & "', Email = '" & txtemail.Text & "', Job_Group = '" & cbojobgroup.Text & "', Employment_Date = '" & dtpemploymentdate.Text & "' WHERE Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid1.Text & "'"

    //lets create new command
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand

    //sets the connection for our command
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandText = pin

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    disconnect()

    MessageBox.Show("Record saved!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Try the given code above and I'm pretty sure It'll work. Goodluck!

Comment: I've done what you've said. Code works too, but again it's leaving me with empty fields :'( see comment above for the screenshot

Comment: oh and heavisa_database is the name of the database. new_employee is the table. I figured it would be best if i just deleted the heavisa_database part because it is unneccesary in the codes

Comment: Then theres your problem dude! Just put `UPDATE new_employee`, don't include the name of the database. If you used my code above, It'll work, just change the `heavisa_database.new_employee` to `new_employee`, in the `pin` part.

Comment: You don't need to include the name of the database anymore since we already assign what/which database to use in the global vars part. Tell me if it worked :p

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. But I think it's a small issue with reading the WHERE Employee_ID = '" & txtemployeeid1.Text & "' .